# Why I can't use single quote inside another single qoute in a PHP variable?

Tags: php

I have created a PHP variable:

```
$msg_gifted='<center><h1>It's a gift! </h1>';
```

If I leave it like this the code is breaking.

When I replace the apostrophe with:

```
$msg_gifted='<center><h1>It is a gift! </h1>';
```

everything works fine.
Is there a known way to solve this?

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Basic, *basic* syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
$msg_gifted="<center><h1>It's a gift! </h1>";
```

or

```
$msg_gifted='<center><h1>It\'s a gift! </h1>';
```

**Updated answer**

You can not use the same quote inside the string without escaping the quote. So you either use different quotes surrounding the string or you escape it with `\`. Simplified your code to show different possibilites which will all have the same output.

String in single `'` quotes

```
$msg = '<h1>It\'s a gift!</h1><img src="http://path-to-image.jpg" />';
```

which is almost the same as tring in double `"` quotes

```
$msg = "<h1>It's a gift!</h1><img src=\"http://path-to-image.jpg\" />";
```

Or string concatenation with different quotes just as you prefer:

```
$msg = "<h1>It's a gift!</h1>";
$msg.= '<img src="http://path-to-image.jpg" />';
```

Comment: this corrected the initial issue but now the <img src="https://some_image_filename"> is not working. The rest of the image url is grey. The $msg_gifted variable is some lines of HTML code actually

Comment: @xbass540 updated the answer

Comment: all the above were helpfull and managed to control my code better by using the concatenation method. i realized that what was totally braking the code was a <center> tag. Is this not allowed in a php variable?

Comment: @xbass540 if the answer answered your question please mark as accepted answer. The [<center> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) is deprecated and you should not use it. But PHP does not care at all about if you have a `<center>` or any other tags defined as strings. Cause that is all you do. You just put together strings in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Put `\` like this way:

```
$msg_gifted='<center><h1>It\'s a gift! </h1>';
```

This is called escaping `'` in string in php.